# Sql Server spatial Find nearest neighbour like in oracle

Tags: sql-server, nearest-neighbor, spatial-query

I'm having a trouble in finding the nearest point in sql server using Long Lat.
I want to pass a longitued and latitude parameter then use it to find the nearest point in that area.

Also is there a way to Select all tables that have a geometry function?

Comment: What have you tried for the former? As to the latter, did you try looking in sys.columns for columns with data type geometry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found a solution to this problem. This might be helpful to someone.
i already add some optimization to this code. the @Points.STBuffer(1) determine the search distance so i only put 1m because i need a exact long and lat because i get it on click.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getFacilityDetailsOnClick]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @long float,
    @lat float
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @points geometry
    SET @points = geometry :: Point(@long,@lat,32651);
    DECLARE @searchArea GEOMETRY;
    SET @searchArea = @Points.STBuffer(1);
    @tbl nvarchar(255)


SELECT @sSQL = 'SELECT FEATID, NAME , @tbl as FACILITYNAME , @facility as FACILITYID FROM (SELECT TOP 1  featid, NAME , geometry.STDistance(@pnts) as distance from '
                + QUOTENAME(@tbl) +' WHERE geometry.Filter(@searchArea) = 1 ORDER BY distance) AS tbl'
    EXEC sp_executesql @sSQL , N'@pnts GEOMETRY , @searchArea GEOMETRY , @tbl nvarchar(255) , @facility int ', @Points , @searchArea , @tbl ,@facility;
```